# Javascript wrapping script into a function

Tags: javascript, function, timer

here i have a simple script which is a countdown timer, here is the code:

```
<span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>
<script>
    var seconds = 60;
    function secondPassed() {
        var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
        var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
        if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
            remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;  
        }
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
        if (seconds == 0) {
            clearInterval(countdownTimer);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Buzz Buzz";
        } else {
            seconds--;
        }
    }
    var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
</script>
```

Now at the moment when i open this page on chrome, it starts the countdown straight away, what im trying to do is make it start the countdown when i click on an image, how would i do this guys?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the interval inside an event handler for the image

```
<span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>
<img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/5/r/I/j/O/k/another-green-start-button.svg" id="image" />

<script>
    var seconds = 60,
        countdownTimer;

    function secondPassed() {
        var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
        var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
        if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
            remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;  
        }
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
        if (seconds == 0) {
            clearInterval(countdownTimer);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Buzz Buzz";
        } else {
            seconds--;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('image').addEventListener('click', function() {
          countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
    }, false);

</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9e5mU/1/)

Comment: +1 being the only one to suggest taking the string `secondPassed()` out of setInterval and just making it a function reference as well as using `addEventListener`

Comment: Thanks alot for this, it helped me out! although it caused one problem, it no longer shows the "Buzz Buzz" when the counter has reached 0

Comment: @PandaBear - Yeah, the timer is now out of scope, fixed that and updated the answer!

Comment: Thanks alot for this, now my only problem is,i would be glad if you could help me, how would i change this so theres multiple images on the page which once clicked on start their own counter too.?? thanks

Comment: @PandaBear - The way it's set up now you'd just create more functions and event handlers. A better approach would be to rewrite the entire thing so you could pass elements and easily create new countdowns.

Comment: Well the thing is, i did do it, i copied the script to a separate file and just called it multiple times with <script src="timer1.js"></script> and it worked as multiple timers appeared, but when i click the first image, it only starts the counter for countdown2 span, why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Use onClick of the image

```
<span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>
<img onClick="startTimer()" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsweets2/40/clock_alarm.png">
<script>
    var seconds = 60;
    function secondPassed() {
        var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
        var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
        if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
            remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;  
        }
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
        if (seconds == 0) {
            clearInterval(countdownTimer);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Buzz Buzz";
        } else {
            seconds--;
        }
    }
    var countdownTimer;
    function startTimer(){
        countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Set a onclick listener on the image itself:

```
<img onclick="setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000)" src="..."/>
```